# getManyReference isn't fired using ra-data-json-server

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I'm exploring [react admin](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin) using [ra-data-json-server](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/tree/master/packages/ra-data-json-server) data provider.

However I can't seem to figure out `getManyReference`.

accordingly to the docs, `getManyReference` should issue a request with the resource id but in practice, I don't see this happening

[image]

As I understand it, the two requests I see are:

1. the `getList` request to fetch the list of reference options
2. the `getOne` request to fetch the specific resource to edit

shouldn't there be a third request `getManyReference` request?

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it is the case, but have you added to Resource?

```
    <Admin ...>
        ...
        <Resource name='permissions' />
        ...
    </Admin>
```